# Restrict S3 bucket access to Identity Pool ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have difficulties to allow access to S3 bucket only to one IdentityPoolId.

I tried such things but it's not working

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ListYourObjects",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "s3:prefix": [
            "cognito/application-name/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Do you have an idea ?
My IdentityPoolId look like : "us-east-1:XXXXXXX"

Thank you!

Comment: `cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub` refers to the user entity.  What do you mean, grant access to an identity pool?

Comment: I am using CognitoIdentity with IdentityPoolId for to get connection to my S3 bucket. For now this bucket is public, and I would like to restrict access only to users authenticated